# How to get ranking position of a mongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb, ranking

I have a mongoDB collection that looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "John Doe",
    "company": "Acme",
    "email": "john.doe@acme.com",
    "matches": [171844, 169729, 173168, 174310, 168752, 174972, 172959, 169546]
}
{
    "_id": 2,
    "name": "Bruce Wayne",
    "company": "Wayne Enterprises",
    "email": "bruce@wayne.com",
    "matches": [171844, 232333, 233312, 123456]
}
{
    "_id": 3,
    "name": "Tony Stark",
    "company": "Stark Industries",
    "email": "tony@stark.com",
    "matches": [173844, 155729, 133168, 199310, 132752, 139972]
}
{
    "_id": 4,
    "name": "Clark Kent",
    "company": "Daily Planet",
    "email": "clark.kent@planet.com",
    "matches": [169729, 174310, 168752]
}
{
    "_id": 5,
    "name": "Lois Lane",
    "company": "Daily Planet",
    "email": "lois.lane@planet.com",
    "matches": [172959, 169546]
}
```

I need to get a filtered list of users but with a key that shows the user's "ranking" position based on the number of "matches" records that it has.
There should be a `global ranking` position and a `company ranking` position.

The desired result should be this (for an example filtering for company='Daily Planet'):

```
{
    _id: 4,
    name: 'Clark Kent',
    company: 'Daily Planet',
    email: 'clark.kent@planet.com',
    points: 3,     // <=
    globalRank: 4, // <=
    companyRank: 1 // <=
},
{
    _id: 5,
    name: 'Lois Lane',
    company: 'Daily Planet',
    email: 'lois.lane@planet.com',
    points: 2,     // <=
    globalRank: 4, // <=
    companyRank: 2 // <=
}
```

Notice that Clark Kent is ranked 4th on the global ranking since he has 3 matches (John Doe, Bruce Wayne and Tony Stark have more matches than him) and is ranked 1st on the company Ranking, since he has more matches than any Daily Planet user.

However, even after several days of research, I couldn't find a way to do it. (I couldn't even figure out how to do the global ranking or company ranking ONLY).

Any ideas on how to solve this, or on how to approach the problem in a different way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic idea is to first sort the points according to the `points` as you have done, following up by `$push` them into an array. This ensures that elements are inserted in the sorted order. We then [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) using the `includeArrayIndex` property to generate the index of the element in the sorted array which corresponds to the rank.

The pipeline using the above logic is as below (try to go stage by stage to understand better) :-

```
aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            name: "$name",
            company: "$company",
            email: "$email",
            points: {
                $size: "$matches"
            }
        }
    }, {
        $sort: {
            points: -1
        }
    },

    {
        $group: {
            _id: {},
            arr: {
                $push: {
                    name: '$name',
                    company: '$company',
                    email: '$email',
                    points: '$points'
                }
            }
        }
    }, {
        $unwind: {
            path: '$arr',
            includeArrayIndex: 'globalRank',
        }
    }, {
        $sort: {
            'arr.company': 1,
            'arr.points': -1
        }
    }, {
        $group: {
            _id: '$arr.company',
            arr: {
                $push: {
                    name: '$arr.name',
                    company: '$arr.company',
                    email: '$arr.email',
                    points: '$arr.points',
                    globalRank: '$globalRank'
                }
            }
        }
    }, {
        $unwind: {
            path: '$arr',
            includeArrayIndex: 'companyRank',
        }
    }, {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            name: '$arr.name',
            company: '$arr.company',
            email: '$arr.email',
            points: '$arr.points',
            globalRank: '$arr.globalRank',
            companyRank: '$companyRank'
        }
    }

]);
```

The output of the query is

```
/* 1 */
{
    "companyRank" : NumberLong(0),
    "name" : "Bruce Wayne",
    "company" : "Wayne Enterprises",
    "email" : "bruce@wayne.com",
    "points" : 4,
    "globalRank" : NumberLong(2)
}

/* 2 */
{
    "companyRank" : NumberLong(0),
    "name" : "Tony Stark",
    "company" : "Stark Industries",
    "email" : "tony@stark.com",
    "points" : 6,
    "globalRank" : NumberLong(1)
}

/* 3 */
{
    "companyRank" : NumberLong(0),
    "name" : "Clark Kent",
    "company" : "Daily Planet",
    "email" : "clark.kent@planet.com",
    "points" : 3,
    "globalRank" : NumberLong(3)
}

/* 4 */
{
    "companyRank" : NumberLong(1),
    "name" : "Lois Lane",
    "company" : "Daily Planet",
    "email" : "lois.lane@planet.com",
    "points" : 2,
    "globalRank" : NumberLong(4)
}

/* 5 */
{
    "companyRank" : NumberLong(0),
    "name" : "John Doe",
    "company" : "Acme",
    "email" : "john.doe@acme.com",
    "points" : 8,
    "globalRank" : NumberLong(0)
}
```

**Ranks are 0 based here.**

Comment: Thanks a lot! "includeArrayIndex" was what I was looking for!!

Comment: @hyades,  is it memory safe? what if there are thousands of documents?

Answer (score 1):

Starting in `Mongo 5`, it's a perfect use case for the new [`$setWindowFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/)  aggregation operator:

```
// { name: "John Doe",    firm: "Acme",              matches: [171844, 169729, 173168, 174310, 168752, 174972, 172959, 169546] }
// { name: "Bruce Wayne", firm: "Wayne Enterprises", matches: [171844, 232333, 233312, 123456] }
// { name: "Tony Stark",  firm: "Stark Industries",  matches: [173844, 155729, 133168, 199310, 132752, 139972] }
// { name: "Clark Kent",  firm: "Daily Planet",      matches: [169729, 174310, 168752] }
// { name: "Lois Lane",   firm: "Daily Planet",      matches: [172959, 169546] }
db.collection.aggregate([

  { $set: { pts: { $size: "$matches" } } },

  { $setWindowFields: {
    sortBy: { pts: -1 },
    output: { globRnk: { $rank: {} } }
  }},

  { $setWindowFields: {
    partitionBy: "$firm",
    sortBy: { pts: -1 },
    output: { firmRnk: { $rank: {} } }
  }}
])
// { name: "John Doe",   firm: "Acme",             pts: 8, globRnk: 1, firmRnk: 1, matches: [171844, 169729, 173168, 174310, 168752, 174972, 172959, 169546] }
// { name: "Tony Stark", firm: "Stark Industries", pts: 6, globRnk: 2, firmRnk: 1, matches: [173844, 155729, 133168, 199310, 132752, 139972] }
// { name: "Bruce Wayne",firm: "Wayne Enterprises",pts: 4, globRnk: 3, firmRnk: 1, matches: [171844, 232333, 233312, 123456] }
// { name: "Clark Kent", firm: "Daily Planet",     pts: 3, globRnk: 4, firmRnk: 1, matches: [169729, 174310, 168752] }
// { name: "Lois Lane",  firm: "Daily Planet",     pts: 2, globRnk: 5, firmRnk: 2, matches: [172959, 169546 ] }
```

The first `$setWindowFields` stage adds the global rank by:

- sorting documents by decreasing order of `points`: `sortBy: { points: -1 }`
- and adding the `globRnk` field in each document (`output: { globRnk: { $rank: {} } }`)

  - which is the rank of the document amongst all documents based on the sorting field `points`: `globRnk: { $rank: {} }`.

The second `$setWindowFields` stage is very similar to the first one, excepts for the rank that's now calculated within each partitions defined by the `firm`: `partitionBy: "$firm"`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting this result? . `result_array` will hold the end result.

```
var my_array = db.testCol.aggregate([{ $project: { _id:1, name:1, company:1, email:1, "points" : {$size: "$matches"}, "globalRank":{$literal: 0}, companyRank:{$literal: 0} } },
{$sort: {points : -1 } },
]).toArray()

var result_array = [];
var companyCount = {};
for (i = 0; i < my_array.length; i++) {
    var company_name = my_array[i].company
    if (companyCount[company_name] == null ){
        companyCount[company_name] = 1;
    }
    else{
        companyCount[company_name] = companyCount[company_name] + 1
    }
    result_array.push({ "_id" : my_array[i]._id, "name": my_array[i].name, "company" : my_array[i].company, "email" : my_array[i].email, "points" : my_array[i].points, "globalRank":i+1 , "companyRank" : companyCount[company_name]})
}

result_array
```

and the Output is:

```
[
        {
                "_id" : 1,
                "name" : "John Doe",
                "company" : "Acme",
                "email" : "john.doe@acme.com",
                "points" : 8,
                "globalRank" : 1,
                "companyRank" : 1
        },
        {
                "_id" : 3,
                "name" : "Tony Stark",
                "company" : "Stark Industries",
                "email" : "tony@stark.com",
                "points" : 6,
                "globalRank" : 2,
                "companyRank" : 1
        },
        {
                "_id" : 2,
                "name" : "Bruce Wayne",
                "company" : "Wayne Enterprises",
                "email" : "bruce@wayne.com",
                "points" : 4,
                "globalRank" : 3,
                "companyRank" : 1
        },
        {
                "_id" : 4,
                "name" : "Clark Kent",
                "company" : "Daily Planet",
                "email" : "clark.kent@planet.com",
                "points" : 3,
                "globalRank" : 4,
                "companyRank" : 1
        },
        {
                "_id" : 5,
                "name" : "Lois Lane",
                "company" : "Daily Planet",
                "email" : "lois.lane@planet.com",
                "points" : 2,
                "globalRank" : 5,
                "companyRank" : 2
        }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

You use $match condition. So, you try this also..

```
db.rank.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        "company": "Daily Planet"
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        name: "$name",
        company: "$company",
        email: "$email",
        points: {
            $size: "$matches"
        }
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        points: -1
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {},
        list: {
            $push: {
                name: '$name',
                company: '$company',
                email: '$email',
                points: '$points'
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: {
        path: '$list',
        includeArrayIndex: 'globalRank',
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        'list.company': 1,
        'list.points': -1
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: '$list.company',
        list: {
            $push: {
                name: '$list.name',
                company: '$list.company',
                email: '$list.email',
                points: '$list.points',
                globalRank: '$globalRank'
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: {
        path: '$list',
        includeArrayIndex: 'companyRank',
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        name: '$list.name',
        company: '$list.company',
        email: '$list.email',
        points: '$list.points',
        globalRank: '$list.globalRank',
        companyRank: '$companyRank'
    }
}]).pretty()
```

OutPut  like this,

```
{
    "companyRank" : NumberLong(0),
    "name" : "Clark Kent",
    "company" : "Daily Planet",
    "email" : "clark.kent@planet.com",
    "points" : 3,
    "globalRank" : NumberLong(0)
}
{
    "companyRank" : NumberLong(1),
    "name" : "Lois Lane",
    "company" : "Daily Planet",
    "email" : "lois.lane@planet.com",
    "points" : 2,
    "globalRank" : NumberLong(1)
}
```